# Manipulate multiple models using matrices?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

How would I go about doing this? So far I've only been able to rotate one model.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what is confusing you? Are you trying to use OpenGL's matrix stack, or your own?

Comment: You might want to include some code with your question. Otherwise we cannot give specific help.

Comment: @Tim I'm using my own matrices and shaders.

Comment: Oh wait, I think I get it now. I bind the vbo, apply matrix, unbind, bind second vbo, then apply new model matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Quote: Oh wait, I think I get it now. I bind the vbo, apply matrix, unbind, bind second vbo, then apply new model matrix?

The only time your matrix has any effect is when you call `glDrawArrays/glDrawElements` or one of their similar derivatives.

The way to draw multiple objects, each with their own matrix would be similar to the following pseudocode:

```
foreach (Object obj in List<Object>) {
    setupVertexAttributes(obj.attributes);   //setup the attributes (VBOs)
    uploadMatrix(obj.matrix);                //set the matrix
    glDrawElements(obj.indices);             //draw the object

}
```